# HTML 5 Video modify through CSS

Tags: html, css

I am styling a HTML 5 video and although and have been able to modify the mute, play and other functions. I am a little stuck on how to get the progress bar to modify? For example from the default grey to red. Any suggestions appreciated.

```
 video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider { display: none; }

video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button { display: none; }

video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button { display: none; }
```

Comment: I think [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos) article will help you.

Answer (score 0):

MDN has a great tutorial. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Video_player_styling_basics . hope it helps

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case link gets removed.